# How can I open an Access database when it shows an "unrecognized database format" error?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-office, ms-access-2003

I have a database in MS Access 2007. I saved it in Access 2002-2003 database format, i.e., `.mdb` format. It was working fine. But today when I try to open it, it shows an error. The error is

> Unrecognized database format 'F:\Project\bin\Debug\database.mdb'.

How can I open this file? I have no backup.

Comment: Look ma...no backup! It's soooo easy to backup an mdb!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Windows Vista and up, you may have a system backup.

Right click the file and select `Restore Previous Versions`.

If this does not work, try [Access Database Corruption Repair Guide](http://www.everythingaccess.com/tutorials.asp?ID=Access-Database-Corruption-Repair-Guide#3)

You could try creating a new empty MDB file and importing the objects from the old one. It might work at least for some of the objects.

Comment: @E Mett
I use windows 7.
when I try to restore previos version it shows that there are no previous versions available.


If I try to importing the object then how can I do it?

Comment: Use `Import and Link` on the `External Data` tab on the `Ribbon`